# Captain form saving form input in a database

Tags: wordpress, forms

i have a question regarding a Wordpress plugin for building forms. It is called Captain Form. It saves all the submitted user input in the form on a cloud/their own databases. 
Is it possible to make a script, that when someone clicks on submit, the information is stored in another database on the server, where the site is stored?

Comment: Yes it is. Where are you stuck?

Comment: In the process of thinking if it even matters actually... I saw that with the free version you can't even send autorespond mails, which is too limited for me. :/

Answer (score 0):

With CaptainForm, if you have your own database you can create a custom script and using Webhooks you can have all submissions sent to your own private database.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It does healp a little bit, thank you;) I will have to check out the webhooks a bit more...